# How can I store large character values in MS Access?

Tags: ms-access, types, jet

I'm using an MS Access database. I want to store a description field having more than 255 characters. What do I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

Use a Memo field instead

Comment: This would work assuming you have the ability to change the table structure.